# How to add target to NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I have a UITextView that has some text, and then should have a clickable string at the end of the paragraph, but I'm not sure how to approach this. I wanted to use attributed strings, but I cannot add a target to the attributed string to make it clickable. How can I accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: You can't add a target, exactly. You can add custom code in your UITextViewDelegate, as described in Ramprasath's answer. You could also create a custom URL scheme and have your app respond to that URL scheme. Then when the user clicks a link, it would invoke your app's URL handling code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UITextViewDelegate to detect iuser interation.

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapTextView: UITextView!

func setupTextView() {
    let mapAttributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Click here to get directions")
    mapAttributedText.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.link, value: "customValue", range: mapAttributedText.mutableString.range(of: "Click here"))
    let linkArr = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue,NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue,NSAttributedString.Key.underlineColor: UIColor.blue] as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]
    mapTextView.linkTextAttributes = linkArr
    mapTextView.attributedText = mapAttributedText
    mapTextView.delegate = self
    mapTextView.isEditable = false
}


extension YourVCName: UITextViewDelegate {
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
        if URL.absoluteString == "customValue" {
            // Do something
        }
         return false
    }
}
```